# how to attach IWebDriver to current web browser using debugging address?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Currently i wanted to attach web driver to the chrome browser. i have added -remote-debugging-port=9222" into my chrome.

Now i want to use the chrome web driver automatic pass in my variable to the user id and password text field.
I have try below code, it hitting error on The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

Below is my sample code.

```
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222";
        //option.AddAdditionalCapability("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        string loginid = "Testing";
        string password = "pasword";
        IWebElement IDTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("UserAbbr"));
        IWebElement PwdTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("UserPassword"));
        IDTextBox.SendKeys(loginid);
        PwdTextBox.SendKeys(password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this constructor: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver__ctor_6.htm

`IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:/drivers", options);`

And put the chromedriver.exe inside C:/drivers

You can also add chromedriver as a resource in your project and configure the build process to always copy it when building. This way you can specify a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Comment: the chromedriver.exe is the selenium chrome driver?

Comment: Happy to hear, my pleasure:)